# Why do ptr and *ptr show the same value when ptr is an array of pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers

I understand that `ptr` is a pointer to the address of `M[0]`.

Therefore, I thought `*ptr` would represent the value of `M[0]`.

But why do the two show the same value?

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    int M[3][3]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
    int (*ptr)[3]; int *p; int **pt;
    ptr = M;
    cout << ptr << " " << *ptr;

    return 0;
}
```

I look forward to a clear answer to this.

Also, I wonder how I can print out `ptr[0]`.

Comment: See [What is array to pointer decay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay)

Comment: `ptr` is not an array of pointers. Instead `ptr` is a pointer to an array of type `int [3]`

Comment: To elaborate on Jasons's comment `int (*ptr)[3];` is a pointer to an array. An array of pointers would be `int* ptr[3];` but obviously then `ptr = M;` would not compile. (Try it an see what the error is).

Comment: Also `*ptr` is exactly the same as `ptr[0]` **by definition**. So the answer to the question how so I print out `ptr[0]` is that you already are.

Comment: Yes, the value of `ptr` is the address of `ptr[0]`, and `*ptr` has the value of `ptr[0]`. But their *types* are different: `int (*)[3]` and `int *` respectively.  Your code is converting both those pointers to `void *` (to call the stream's `operator<<()` overload that accepts a `void *` argument).  `(void *)ptr` is the address of the first byte in the array `{1,2,3}`, and `(void *)(*ptr)` is the address of the first byte in the `1` - which is the first element of the array `{1,2,3}`.  So the address of the same byte is being printed both times.

Comment: @Peter Are you sure? `*ptr` and `ptr[0]` are identical in type and value for any pointer.

Comment: @john I didn't say what you're thinking.   The OP is asking why `ptr` and `*ptr`, when printed, both result in the same output (i.e. the pointers have the same printed value).

Comment: @Peter OK got it, I mistook what *their* was referencing in your second sentence.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do `ptr` and `*ptr` show the same value when `ptr` is an array of pointers?

Your interpretation of `ptr` is wrong. In particular, `ptr` is not an array of pointers, but is a pointer to an array of type `int[3]`.

This means that the type of `ptr` is `int (*)[3]`, which in turn means that the type of `*ptr` is `int[3]`. Now, due to a property called **array to pointer decay**, this resulting array decays to `int*` (meaning a pointer to its first element) and gives you the output you observed.

More importantly, note that `ptr` points to the first inner array `{1,2,3}` which has the same value as `*ptr`. That is, ***the type of `ptr` and `*ptr` are different but their value is same for a given array.***

---

> I wonder how I can print out `ptr[0]`.

From the above discussion, we can see that `*ptr` is the same as `ptr[0]`, so you're already getting the value you want.